# How recent is getLastLocation?

Tags: java, android, google-location-services

I'm currently making an Android app for myself, for fun, and wish to get the current location. *Maybe* I'll publish this on Play Store.

I was reading on the most convenient way to get the current location, but because of the note [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies), I decided to go the Google way. Eventually, my research got me on a `getLastLocation` [example](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known).

However, what bugs me is how often does this get updated? Is there a way to know how recent this location is? When I call that method, will the device try to update "last location" then return it to me?

I tried to research about it, but the best answer I got is

> Returns the best most recent location currently available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what bugs me is how often does this get updated?

Possibly never.

> Is there a way to know how recent this location is?

There is [a `getTime()` method on `Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime()) that tells you the system time at which that `Location` was determined.

> When I call that method, will the device try to update "last location" then return it to me?

No.

Comment: So getLastLocation is barely ever useful? I can't think of a case where I want the location but don't care if it's completely wrong.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: People only move so fast. If all you need is state/province-level results, and you do not want to be continuously observing their location, `getLastLocation()` may be useful. But, yes, on the whole, I would expect few apps to use it.